# Compiled Emacs Needs Terminfo

Tags: compilation

When installing emacs completely from source to a custom prefix (no root), even after the compilation works, it says `emacs: Cannot open terminfo database file`
. Adding the terminfo to different parts of the PATH/other environment variables doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

Using strace (`strace emacs`), it only looks at `stat`s `~/.terminfo` and `~/share/terminfo`. Copying a terminfo database (it was installed at a different location on my computer) to `~/.terminfo` works.